# How to fix "__new__() missing 3 required positional arguments:.." error in Python

Tags: python, namedtuple

I'm working on a python code and I get this error: 
"TypeError: **new**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'name', 'freq', and 'gen'"

I'm importing a csv file to create a list of tuples, using a namedtuple.

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

Rec = namedtuple('Rec', 'year, name, freq, gen')

def read_file(file):  
    with open(file) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            recs= Rec(line)
        return recs

read_file("./data/file.csv")
```

It's probably some newbie problem, but that's what I am :)
I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line` is a tuple.  When you call `Rec(line)`, that entire tuple gets interpreted as the `year` argument (with the other three arguments being missing, hence the error).

To fix this, change

```
recs = Rec(line)
```

to

```
recs = Rec(*line)
```

or

```
recs = Rec._make(line)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make